# C++ Constructor issue

Tags: c++, class, constructor, crash

I have a class for loading and render objects in OpenGL. For loading objects I have a function called **LoadFile(std::string FilePath)** which work just fine but now I also want to load a file from the constructor so I tried doing this:

```
CObject(std::string FilePath)
{
    CObject(); // set all values to 0
    LoadFile(FilePath);
}
```

But doing this crashes my app whenever I try to render and I really have no idea why :s.

Comment: Error message? Did you try a debugger? What's in `CObject()`? And please work on your acception rate.

Comment: Better create another member function which does those assignments and call it in constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Calling a constructor of the same class from within a constructor won't work as Java (that is delegate some of the job to a more generic constructor). That syntax there just means that you're creating a new temporary object with the default constructor.

The only close thing is C++11's delegated constructor:

```
CObject(std::string FilePath): CObject()
{
    LoadFile(FilePath);
}
```

Comment: Sure you **CAN** call a constructor from within a constructor.

Comment: Actually you can, it just doesn't do what you expect, it creates a temporary which then immediately goes out of scope.  This shouldn't crash the program in and of it's self though.  But it might for indirect reasons.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore sure you _SHOULDN'T_

Comment: @LorenzoPistone it depends on what you're trying to do. You might want to intialize some members. But saying "You cannot call a constructor from within a constructor." **is just wrong**.

Comment: @M3taSpl0it that's completely different.

Comment: @M3taSpl0it I assure you, I know what it does. I know it creates a temporary, I know it doesn't change `this`, but **you can**.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore edited. I'm always too concise in my writing.

Comment: As per your edit - how does it work in Java? Are you talking about `super()`? Because in C++ you **can** call base class constructors.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore No, I'm talking about calling a constructor of the same class, and expect it to work on the same being-constructed object. Still too concise?

Comment: You still haven't corrected the most important part - that you can't call a constructor from a constructor. It's still wrong.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore *In C++03* you cannot call a constructor from another constructor *of the same class for the same object*. Also you don't have to explicitly specify every single detail that can be understood from context.

Comment: @n.m. **I know**. I'm pointing out an obvious mistake so he can make the appropriate corrections. I never said you can do that for the same object, neither did he. Proof: http://ideone.com/XNzen

Comment: @n.m. What if the op is a beginner? He sees someone with 700+ rep on SO that says "You cannot call a constructor from within a constructor" and takes this as a rule, because someone inexperienced can't see the context you see. **You have to specify the details, and this isn't just a detail. It's wrong!**. I can't believe I'm arguing about this.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore as n.m. said, you're being pretty pedantic, but I edited my answer again anyway.

Comment: Thank you! I am, but for a beginner it makes a big difference. It's sufficient for someone to throw "you can't do this" out there and they might take it as a rule.

Comment: @Lorenzo : Pedantry is necessary in order to educate anyone. If you leave out pertinent details, how will the OP learn those pertinent details? Walking away half-informed is worse than walking away without any answer at all.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore: Let's just agree to disagree on the methodology of teaching, OK?

Comment: I tried removing CObject() and setting all values manually but I get the same problem. Could the problem be that LoadFile is in another class that is being inherited by my CObject class? I uploaded the two classes to pastebin if anyone want to have a look: http://pastebin.com/siJtN3Kk

Comment: @Traxmate since your code in the question basically did nothing plus call `LoadFile(FilePath)`, removing the bad constructor call will just skip the "nothing" and call `LoadFile(FilePath)`. Did you forget to do correctly what you intended to do, that is initialize your object? Is `LoadFile` ok?

Comment: @Traxmate: A few hundred lines long uncompilable fragment of code is not anyone's idea to spend an hour. If you can't narrow the problem to a small compilable self-contained example, then the question is not for this site.

Comment: I've done some more debugging and I at least now know why it is crashing... Apparently the destructors of the inherited classes are being called which of course  unloads all the data. Is there anyway to stop the destructors from being called?

Comment: @n.m. we're already disagreeing. You think it's okay to omit important stuff, and actually provide wrong info, I don't.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore: You are perfectly welcome to decide for yourself which things are important and which are not.

Comment: @n.m. Ok I see. Lorenzo edited the question and, IMO, that's enough. And I really hope it's just stubbornness on your behalf that makes you go on with this. You do realize that you're saying "It's ok to give out false information, people can read between the lines"? I'm not going to waste any more time with your nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `CObject();` doesn't set all values to 0, but creates a temporary object. It should be:

```
CObject(std::string FilePath)
{
    //manually set fields to 0
    LoadFile(FilePath);
}
```

If your default constructor also calls itself again, it's most probably a stack overflow error.

Comment: @ildjarn does pointing out something wrong in a different answer not count?

Comment: Apparently to some people... ;-/

Comment: I did that but the I get the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the `CObject()` constructor to set all values to 0.  You are actually creating a temporary `CObject` instead of setting all of the current objects values to 0.

What you need to do is either create a private initialization method that both the default and other constructors can call before loading a file or initialize the objects members in the `CObject(std::string FilePath)` constructor.